# How can I update array objects and also add objects to an array simultaneously?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Sample Data:

```
{
  "invoice_no": "a2",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "shoes",
      "qty": 3,
      "price": 200
    },
    {
      "name": "jeans",
      "qty": 5,
      "price": 500
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update the existing objects in items array and also add another objects to the same array if any, at the same time.

Comment: What have you created so far?

Comment: @kevin i m confused which operator to use with the update query using mongodb

Comment: Which property in the array object(s) do you like to update?

Comment: What have you tried? Do remember, this isn't a code writing service, we're happy to help when you have a concrete problem, but asking us to give you the code for something is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

According the MongoDB documentation, you could use multiple update operator modifiers https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter

I think you could try this:

```
db.collection.update({"invoice_no": "a2", "items.name": "shoes"}, {$push: {"name":"shorts", "qty":10, "price":200}, $set: {"items.$.qty": 5}});
```

You should also read this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Update with $addToSet

```
db.collection.update({"invoice_no": "a2", "items.name": "shoes"}, {$push: {"name":"shorts", "qty":10, "price":200}, $addToSet: {["extra_field":"ABC"]}});
```

Comment: Actually i was trying with "$addToSet" operator but it only appends obj to array. But if i pass 3 objects from view and currently there are 2 objects in array, i want the existing 2 objects in db to update and add the remaining objects in the array. Pls help. Thanks for the answer @Kevin

Comment: Pushing 3 objects to the array is not the problem right?

Comment: No, updating the existing objects is a problem here. Pushing is working fine but i need to update the existing objects and add the remaining ones.